# How can a row of a matrix created by nested defaultdict be accessed in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, defaultdict

I am creating a word cooccurrence matrix in Python and using nested defaultdicts to create the matrix. I have successfully created the matrix and stored the word counts, but am now having trouble when trying to get back a vector (row of matrix) from the nested defaultdict.

Here is the line of code I used to initialize the matrix:

`matrix = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))`

Here are the lines I used to put the word counts into the matrix:

```
matrix[target_word_id][collocated_word_id] += 1

matrix[collocated_word_id][target_word_id] += 1
```

And this is how I am trying to access a row of the matrix for a row corresponding to the given word id:

```
vector1 = matrix[word1_id]
```

When I print vector1 to test my work, this is what I get as the output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {})
```

The full code for that class is here. I am calling the functions from a separate main class:

```
class Create_vector():

    def build_vocab(self, corpus):
        vocab = collections.defaultdict(int)
        i = 1

        for line in corpus:
            token = line.strip()
            if token not in vocab:
                vocab[token] = i
                i += 1

        return vocab



    def build_cooccurrence(self, corpus, vocab, window):

        matrix = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))

        for x, line in enumerate(corpus):

            if x % 100000 == 0:
                print('Building cooccurrence matrix: on line %i', x)
            tokens = line.strip()
            token_ids = [vocab[token] for token in tokens]

            for i, target_word_id in enumerate(token_ids):

                collocated_word_ids = token_ids[min(0, target_word_id - window): target_word_id]

                for j, collocated_word_id in enumerate(collocated_word_ids):

                    matrix[target_word_id][collocated_word_id] += 1

                    matrix[collocated_word_id][target_word_id] += 1

        return matrix


    def get_vector(self, matrix, vocab, weight, word1, word2):

        if weight == 'FREQ':

            if word1 in vocab:
                word1_id = vocab[word1]
                vector1 = matrix[word1_id]
                pprint.pprint(vector1)
```

The main class is here:

```
import nltk
    import sys
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    import create_vector
    import pprint
    import string


def main():
    brown_words = list(nltk.corpus.brown.words())
    window = int(sys.argv[1])
    weight = sys.argv[2]
    brown_words_lower = [word.lower() for word in brown_words]
    brown_words_only = [w for w in brown_words_lower if w not in string.punctuation]
    stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    brown_words_filtered = [w for w in brown_words_only if w not in stops]

    vector = create_vector.Create_vector()

    vocab = vector.build_vocab(brown_words_filtered)
    cooccurrence = vector.build_cooccurrence(brown_words_filtered, vocab, window)

    for line in text:
        words = line.split(',')
        word1 = words[0]
        word2 = words[1]
        vector1, vector2 = vector.get_vector(cooccurrence, vocab, weight, word1, word2)
```

And the command to run it is:
python3.4 main.py 2 FREQ

Comment: Your question will be more clear if you add a sample input and its output!

Comment: `tokens = line.strip()`
`token_ids = [vocab[token] for token in tokens]`
Are you sure you don't intend to use `str.split`?

Comment: I think that strip() is correct. I've been printing things out along the way and the vocab list and cooccurrence matrix seemed correct to me while using strip(). Additionally since I'm taking just the words from the Brown corpus, they are already configured in a list.

Comment: A list has no `strip` attribute, so your `tokens` variable must be a string at that point. If you iterate through it, you iterate through the individual characters in your string.
If you think I'm incorrect, just print out `tokens` and see.

Comment: When I print out tokens I get a list of words, such as this:   able
gauge
swift
greedy
glance
figure

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce:

```
>>> import collections
>>> matrix = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(int))
>>> matrix[2][3] += 1
>>> matrix[3][2] += 1
>>> vector1 = matrix[2]
>>> vector1
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {3: 1})
```

Are you sure the value in your `word1_id` equals a value that is already inserted into the matrix?
Could you post your complete code, not just scraps of it?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the id equals a value that is already inserted into the matrix. I only generate the value if the word is in the vocabulary which is generated from the corpus that I'm building the matrix on. Additionally, all of the vectors for my word list are returning that output